# About Android Application in Google Play

Tags: android

I am trying to upload android application (.apk) in google play,is it necessary to have licence key for a (.apk) in paid application.If yes Why it is required?

MyLicenseCheckerCallback throws error that it should implement then super type method.
its says allow() must pass an  integer argument which argument in should pass 
can you suggest me with some helps.

```
private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
@Override
public void allow() {
        if (isFinishing()) {
                        // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                        return;
}
// Should allow user access.
startMainActivity();

            }

@Override
public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
    if (isFinishing()) {
        // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
        return;
    }
    // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
    // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
    // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
    toast("Error: " + errorCode.name());
    startMainActivity();

}

@Override
public void dontAllow() {
    if (isFinishing()) {
        // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
        return;
    }

    // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
    // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
    // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
    // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
    // restricted set of features.
    // In this example, we show a dialogue that takes the user to Market.
    showDialog(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read this article you got idea why license key is needed

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?hl=ta

please follow the steps to create a release private signing key:

Select File -> Export

1. In the pop-up, expand Android and select Export Android Application
2. In the next pop-up, select the Browse button and select the Project
   you need to publish the APK of.
3. Click the Next button. The next set of options, is for selecting an
   existing Keystore or creating a new one. Choose Create new keystore,
   set a location where you want to save the keystore file, choose your
   own password and confirm the same.
4. Next page is the Key Creation set of options. In this, create an
   alias for the keystore. Again, choose a password and confirm the
   same. Set a validity in number of years for your keystore. It has to
   be a minimum 25 years. Enter the rest of the details on this page.
5. On the final page of this wizard, choose the location where you want
   the APK to be saved on your computer.

That's all there is to it.

**NOTE: The release signing key is to be created by the developer and not by Google for the dev. It is a self signed certificate. Keep this key safe and secure, and possibly in multiple locations. If you are to loose access to the signing key file created in Step 4 above, you will not be able to publish updates to your application. There are no known ways of recovering a lost key. The same applies to the passwords you select in the process above. Do not loose either the key file or it's passwords.**

Comment: How to Add licence key in the (.apk)?

Comment: Kindly verify the above posting.